# pushing the helm chart to azure container registry fails

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-container-registry

I get the below error when I try to push the chart to ACR. Can you suggest the steps to be done here?

"This command is implicitly deprecated because command group 'acr helm' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use 'helm v3' instead."

I followed this article to create helm chart

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2018/11/27/tutorial-azure-devops-setup-cicd-pipeline-kubernetes-docker-helm/

These articles also describe the issue, but I don't understand what needs to be done to fix it.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14498
https://gitanswer.com/azure-cli-az-acr-helm-commands-not-working-python-663770738
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14467

Here is the yaml script which throws error

```
- bash: |
    cd $(projectName)
    chartPackage=$(ls $(projectName)-$(helmChartVersion).tgz)
    az acr helm push \
        -n $(registryName) \
        -u $(registryLogin) \
        -p '$(registryPassword)' \
        $chartPackage



 Chart.yaml
         apiVersion: v1
         description: first helm chart create 
          name: helmApp
          version: v0.3.0
```

Comment: can you paste the helm chart syntax(Chart.yaml)?

Comment: @LeiYang I added chart.yaml in the question

Comment: `apiVersion: v1` should be helm2. in helm3, should be `apiVersion: v2`

Comment: I changed to v2, that didn't fix the issue?? any other changes would be required?

Comment: i'm not sure. please try `helm package` to local tar.gz then some ways(there must be some) to upload to the azure restry?

Comment: Which version of Helm are you using? More information available in the article [Push and pull Helm charts to an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos)

Answer (score 5):

Azure has deprecated the support managing Helm charts using the Az Cli. So you will need Helm client version `3.7.1` to push the Helm charts to ACR.

To push the Helm charts to ACR, follow the next steps:

1. Enable OCI support

   ```
   export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
   ```
2. Save your chart to a local archive

   ```
   cd chart-dir
   helm package .
   ```
3. Authenticate with the registry using `helm registry login` command

   ```
   helm registry login $ACR_NAME.azurecr.io \
     --username $USER_NAME \
     --password $PASSWORD
   ```
4. Push chart to the registry as OCI artifact

   ```
   helm push chart-name-0.1.0.tgz oci://$ACR_NAME.azurecr.io/helm
   ```

You can use the above steps in the Azure DevOps pipeline and it will work as expected. For more info on pushing helm charts to ACR, refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos).

Comment: Would be nice if they added a yaml task example for this using the integrated Service Connection instead of username/password variables.

Answer (score 1):

Export the variable `HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1` as part of the bash script. Azure Chart Museums in ACR are OCI registries and therefore need this ENV variable set in order to push.

Upon closer examination of the question You should ise the built in task for this

````
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: Helm save
  inputs:
    command: save
    chartNameForACR: '<chart_name>:<tag>'
    chartPathForACR: <chart_dir>
    azureSubscriptionEndpointForACR: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
    azureResourceGroupForACR: $(REGISTRY_RESOURCE_GROUP)
    azureContainerRegistry: $(REGISTRY_NAME)
```
````

Comment: I tried setting the ADO variable HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1 and run but still I have same issue

Comment: In that case, you need to do the following (this is what I do)


```- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: Helm save
  inputs:
    command: save
    chartNameForACR: '<chart_name>:<tag>'
    chartPathForACR: <chart_dir>
    azureSubscriptionEndpointForACR: $(SERVICE_CONNECTION)
    azureResourceGroupForACR: $(REGISTRY_RESOURCE_GROUP)
    azureContainerRegistry: $(REGISTRY_NAME)
```

Comment: I tried using the built in task for publish the charts to ACR. But the ADO pipeline keeps throwing error `unknown command "chart" for "helm"`  and this is the command it runs `/usr/local/bin/helm chart save /home/vsts/work/1/s/charts`. helm chart command is deprecated. How come it inbuilt task are using this command. Helm Version is v3.7.2+g663a896

Comment: Azure has not yet updated their built-in tasks for the breaking changes in 3.7. Set your helm version to 3.6.x and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @DerekWilliams how do I do that? I added a task before it but that didn't work:
`- task: HelmInstaller@0
  displayName: Install Helm 3.6.x
  inputs:
    helmVersion: 3.6.3`